# Configurar usuario y contraseña de apache tomcat 8.5.24

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, java-9

Estoy tratando de hacer iniciar apache tomcat 8.5.24 según la información que aparece acá: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_l3iCrTAP-A

Instalé el jdk 9.0.1, hice la variable para java jdk y modifiqué la variable `PATH`.

También modifiqué el archivo `tomcat-users.xml` para otorgar los permisos, pero no logro acceder a la página `localhost:8080` porque me pide nombre de usuario y contraseña. Alguien sabe como acceder a esta página?

Answer (score 4):

Deberías validar que en el archivo tomcat-users.xml te haya quedado descomentado estas líneas:

```
<tomcat-users>
 <!--
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="role1"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
 <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
 <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
 -->

 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

En la línea :

```
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

puedes poner el usuario y password que desees y con esas credenciales deberías poder loguearte para ingresar al admin del servidor Tomcat.